# DFA that accepts strings over {b} of length 2i+5k for any non-negative values of i and k

Tags: algorithm, finite-automata, automata, dfa

DFA that accepts strings over {b} of length 2i+5k for any non-negative values of i and k?

What will be the solution to this?

Comment: hint: the language includes all strings of >=4 bs

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? Your question lacks detail, and shows no effort at all on your part to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with finding all words that this DFA accepts. First, there is an empty string (`i=0, k=0`), then `bb (i=1, k=0`), `bbbb (i=2, k=0)` and `bbbbb (i=0, k=1)`. From this point you can generate all words that have more than five `b`s - even are of the form `2*i`, and odd are of the form `5 + 2*i`.

This is the desired DFA:
[image]